# Tool to identify problems in catch blocks

Tags: variables, static, try-catch, analysis

I am looking for a tool (may be build time or eclipse plugin) that can help me to identify if I am not logging the Exception trace/message.

We have a legacy application that has try catch block in which a custom error message is logged. The exception is not logged and is not thrown. So, when a problem occurs, there is no stack trace in the log files that would help to debug the issue. An example of this is:

```
try {  
 do something....  
  } catch (Throwable exception) {  
    Log.log("<<custom message>>");  
  }
```

I need a tool like Coverity or Checkstyle that can help me to identify all such occurrences in my code base.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect you to be able to do a decent job with any tool that can search text using regular expressions (e.g, **grep**).

The regex would be something like this:

```
     "catch\W*\(.*\)\W*{\W*Log\.log"
```

where W stands for some whitespace recognizer that picks up blank and newline.

Your pattern is unique enough I'd expect very few false hits, if the programmers
were consistent with the convention you showed.

[EDIT]  OP indicates

*I am looking for catch blocks where I am NOT doing the following - '+ exception':*

```
  try { do something.... }
       catch (Throwable exception)
      { Log.log("<<custom message>>" + exception)
```

We're back to a regular expression as a pretty decent hack. You need hunt for anyplace that doesn't call Log.log("<<....>", or if it does, doesn't have a following "+exception".
This is awkward to code as a regexp without a "not" operator, but possible. Assuming
the catch clause exists (a different regexp test), and the Log.log call exists, this will probably do it:

```
  "catch\W*\(.*\)\W*{\W*Log\.log\(\".*\+^[\+]"
```

The last check looks to see if "+" is there.  Anything matching this doesn't have the "+".

Our Source Code Search Engine (SCSE) uses the lexemes of the language rather than regexes to enable straightforward searches, so it has a slightly unusual query language written in terms of language lexemes.   It also allows "negation" on a larger scale; you can subtract hits in two regions, and that's really useful.   This means the following query would do the trick:

```
   'catch' '(' I  I ')' '{' I -  I=Log '.' I=log '(' S '+' I ')'
```

This finds hits for all "catch" clauses and the start of the block (assuming it starts with "Log", and subtracts away any matches to the logging idiom.  Quoted terms are language atoms.  I stands for "I(dentifier)"; it can be any identifier (just I) or constrained to a particular regex for the identifier (of which "Log" is a particularly simple regex).  S stands for "S(tring)", also allowing constraints which we don't need for this query.  This query has two sub-queries, one part before the minus sign that finds "catch" clauses and a prefix of the catch body, and one part after the minus sign that looks for that idiom OP insists he wants.  Any overlaps of results of the second subquery with the first cause the overlapped queries to be "subtracted"  (the minus sign) from the result.  So the final result are "catch clauses that don't start with a logging step".

A more sophisticated check requires finding the catch clauses, and logging clauses, and verifying that the logging clauses do not occur anywhere in the catch block.  The SCSE can't do this by itself.   More sophisticated engines that parse and build ASTs can be used to determine this.  I know of tools that can do, this too, if OP wants further elaboration.

Comment: May be I was not able to explain myself. The problem is not to identify if Log.log statement is present. The problem is that the Exception trace/message is not logged or the exception is not thrown.. The above example illustrates such a scenario where the exception is killed by logging a custom message.

Comment: You specifically asked how to identify all these.  I understand the exception is killed by the log call.  What you are apparantly not being clear about, it exactly what you want.  You want to find places where the exception is not killed?  You want to generate traces in all places where the log occurs?

Comment: I am not sure what confusion you have. The very first line - help me to identify if I am not logging the Exception trace/message.- clearly specifies what i am looking for.

Comment: So you want to find out where you are NOT doing the log call?

Comment: I am looking for catch blocks where I am NOT doing the following - '+ exception':

try {  
 do something....  
  } catch (Throwable exception) {  
    Log.log("<<custom message>>" + exception);}